# Delay Actions in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, delay

I want to make an Activity Indicator start animating and then stop after one second.

So does anyone know how I could do that?

```
class stuff {
@IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

   func iGotTriggeredBySomething {
      indicator.startAimating()
      //delay?
      indicator.stopAnimating()
   }
}
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: See `NSTimer` or `dispatch_after`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`dispatch_after()` is the standard way of delaying actions.

```
indicator.startAnimating()

let delay = 4.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

See: [dispatch_after - GCD in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift)

---

**Update for Swift 3.0**

```
indicator.startAnimating()

let delay = Int(4.5 * Double(1000))
DispatchQueue.main.after(when: .now() + .milliseconds(delay)) {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

However, in the spirit of Swift 3.0, I think extending `DispatchQueue` would be a better solution.

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    func delay(_ timeInterval: TimeInterval, execute work: () -> Void) {
        let milliseconds = Int(timeInterval * Double(1000))
        after(when: .now() + .milliseconds(milliseconds), execute: work)
    }
}
```

This leaves us with a very nice

```
indicator.startAnimating()

DispatchQueue.main.delay(4.5) {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

---

**Update 2**

Digging into the Xcode 8.0 beta, I found `public func +(time: DispatchTime, seconds: Double) -> DispatchTime`. So, I guess this is valid…

```
indicator.startAnimating()

DispatchQueue.main.after(when: .now() + 4.5) {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

I don't think there is a need to extend `DispatchQueue` for something this clean already.

--

***Update for Swift 3.1***

There is new syntax for Swift 3.1. They just likes to change things don't they.

```
indicator.startAnimating()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.5) {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Your swift 3 example doesn't seem to work with latest swift 3.1

Comment: @zingle-dingle Thanks for the note: I updated my answer.

Comment: @JefferyThomas I have to thank you for this detailed answer. +1 greatly deserved! :-)

Answer (score 11):

With the updated Swift 3 syntax this becomes

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.5) {
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Swift 5.5 Thankssss

Answer (score 10):

Here is a cleaner and more expressive code to do this using **Swift 3.1** and Grand Central Dispatch:

**Swift 3.1:**

```
indicator.startAnimating()

// Runs after 1 second on the main queue.
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1) ) { 
    indicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

Also `.seconds(Int)`, `.microseconds(Int)` and `.nanoseconds(Int)` may be used for the time.

Answer (score 4):

New in iOS 10, [Timer has a block initializer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/2091888-init) that executes on the main thread.  Its also slightly more flexible because you can take a reference to the Timer and cancel it or reschedule it after the fact.

```
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) {_ in 
    }
```